# C++ Builder 2010

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-2010, c++builder, c++builder-2010

Can someone suggest me a book\s that i can read and learn about C++ Builder 2010.

Comment: That's an incredibly general question. Do you already know C++? Do you want to learn about GUI programming? Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most books available are for Builder C++ 6.0  (from Borland). Many of the lessons in such books are still valid.  Besides reading what @Tony had to say, google for BCB 6 books as well.  Some are now available free on the net, I think.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google for "C++ Build 2010 books" turned up this [link to a PDF](http://www.oopschool.com/books/CPB2010.pdf)

You didn't say in your question what *specifically* it is you want to learn.

Comment: +1 nice find, great for the beginner